# (Flask) Ajax JSON com JQuery-Datatable

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, jquery-datatables, flask

Boa tarrde.

Estou tentando mostrar meus dados (JSON) em uma tabela Datatable via Ajax.
O HTML é:

```
        <div class="x_content">
            <table id="exemplo" name="exemplo" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Data</th>
                        <th>Cred</th>
                        <th>Deb</th>
                        <th>Dsc</th>
                        <th>Valor</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
            </table>
        </div>
```

Com o seguinte script rodando dentro do HTML:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){ 
        $('#exemplo').DataTable({
            "ajax" : '../files/data.json'
            "columns" : [
                { "data" = "data" }
                { "data" = "cred" }
                { "data" = "deb" }
                { "data" = "dsc" }
                { "data" = "valor" } 
            ]
        })
    }   
</script>
```

Como estou usando o Flask com as propriedades de herança de templates, uso o

```
{% block content %}
{% endblock %}
```

Que puxa todo o resto da página de um arquivo base.html.
No arquivo base.html eu faço o load dos seguintes scripts:

```
<script src="static/vendors/datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="static/vendors/datatables.net-bs/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="static/vendors/datatables.net-buttons/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script src="static/vendors/datatables.net-buttons-bs/js/buttons.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="static/vendors/datatables.net-buttons/js/buttons.flash.min.js"></script>
<script src="static/vendors/datatables.net-buttons/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
<script src="static/vendors/datatables.net-buttons/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>
<script src="static/vendors/datatables.net-fixedheader/js/dataTables.fixedHeader.min.js"></script>
<script src="static/vendors/datatables.net-keytable/js/dataTables.keyTable.min.js"></script>
<script src="static/vendors/datatables.net-responsive/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js"></script>
<script src="static/vendors/datatables.net-responsive-bs/js/responsive.bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="static/vendors/datatables.net-scroller/js/dataTables.scroller.min.js"></script>
```

Entretanto, não aparece nada na minha tabela, apenas o título.
Alguém tem alguma ideia do que posso estar fazendo errado?
Já li tudo o que encontrei na internet, mas não consigo fazer o código funcionar...

Já tentei todos os códigos na documentação do DataTable ([link](https://datatables.net/manual/ajax)), e nada.

O HTML fica dentro de app/templates, e o JSON esta no app/files

Comment: A referência ao jQuery esta inciada antes das dependencias de DataTables ? Outra possibilidade é do seu json não estar correto. Outra duvida, essa tabela vem inserida na DOM de carregamento ou é inserida depois do carregamento ?

Comment: Obrigado! De fato um dos problemas era que o script estava sendo carregado no final da página, então dava erro... mudei isso, mas mesmo assim não conseguia exibir... Agora estou tentando trabalhar em script em Python que retorna um JSON (sem necessáriamente salvar um arquivo) data.json para executar o JQuery que puxa esse script, na linha do processamento do lado do servidor (e depois mostra as infos em uma tabela e/ou gráfico)... ainda meio perdido em relação à como fazer isso, mas preciso ler mais para entender qual é o melhor caminho...

Comment: você não conseguindo saber o formato do json ou como gerar com python ? podes fazer outra pergunta caso ache necessário